# How to download file from blob url in webview android java

Tags: java, android-studio, webview, blob

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.setMimeType(mimetype);
        String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
        request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookie);
        request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
        request.setDescription("Downloading...");
        String outputFileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype);
        request.setTitle(outputFileName);
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, outputFileName);
        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        manager.enqueue(request);
    }
});
```

here `url` is starting from blob, example--> `blob:https://www.test.com/c14bc5a8-b13c`

I am getting this error and my app crashes:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only download HTTP/HTTPS URIs: blob:https://www.test.com/c14bc5a8-b13c

Comment: Have you tried it without the `blob:` prefix?

Comment: yes, returning error 404.